# Is it possible to batch send email submissions from a Webform?

Tags: webforms, emails

I'm using a webform to send emails to around 100 people at a time, by sending a submission to all authenticated users. The Drupal side of things handles this fine. However, the email service I'm using (Postmark) only accepts 50 recipients per email and will therefore not deliver the emails.

Postmark says this is a hard limit for them, so my question is: is possible to send webform submission emails in batches, and therefore avoid the problem?

Whether this is a module, or a custom module, any advice is appreciated.

It's a Drupal 9 site.

Thank you